# How do I search for an available Python package using pip?

Tags: python, pip

I would like to be able to search for an available Python package using `pip` (on the terminal). I would like a functionality similar to `apt-cache` in Ubuntu. More specifically, I would like to

1. be able to search for packages given a term (similar to `apt-cache search [package-name]`), and
2. list all available packages.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

To search for a package, issue the command

```
pip search [package-name]
```

Comment: Also, if anyone forgets the command you can find it by typing into the command line: pip -h

Comment: "SEARCH" does NOT work anymore (this is by desing) (as of 01/2021) - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65485498/4940240 answer ny @azcarbea below

Comment: I'm getting "ERROR: XMLRPC request failed [code: -32500]
RuntimeError: PyPI's XMLRPC API is currently disabled due to unmanageable load and will be deprecated in the near future. See https://status.python.org/ for more information."

Comment: This is so far out of date, it should be removed.

Answer (score 161):

**As of Dec 2020, `pip search` will not work ([more](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5216)).**

The current feasible solution is to search online, on: https://pypi.org/ (reference also provided by previous comments).

If anyone hitting the following error:

```
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault -32500: "RuntimeError: PyPI's XMLRPC API has been temporarily
disabled due to unmanageable load and will be deprecated in the near future.
See https://status.python.org/ for more information.">
```

as stated in [#5216](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5216):

> As an update: XMLRPC search does still remain disabled.

because:

> As noted in [#5216 (comment)](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5216#issuecomment-747779286), a group of servers are hitting the pip search entry point, to an extent that PyPI cannot sustain that load with the current architecture of how pip search works.

***Update:*** As a CLI alternative to `pip`, that uses PyPI registry, one can use [poetry](/questions/tagged/poetry):

```
$ poetry search <package>
```

**Update** [2023-05-01]: Altenative: `[pip_search](https://github.com/victorgarric/pip_search)` is an alternative to `pip search` and using `shell aliases`, one can overwrite the `pip search` with the actual execution of `pip_search` (complements to [Johan](https://github.com/victorgarric/pip_search))

---

Comment: for a minimalistic package name search perhaps `wget -O - https://pypi.org/simple/ | grep -i [package name]` You can then get more info if desired at **`https://pypi.org/project/`** `[project name]` *(The match from the grep command between `>....<`)*

Comment: "minimalistic" indeed: [pypi.org/simple](https://pypi.org/simple/) is 290,000 package names `0 .. zzzZZZzzz`, that's it; /project/ has only links to tar / whl. Does anyone know of a pypi mirror with only package*.dist-info for querying (yolk, qypi), no wheels ?

Comment: Why I've downvoted : the question clearly asks "How do I search for an available Python package using pip?" not "why". This answer doesn't give any clue how for help

Comment: The Answer to the Question is "You Can't." The ONLY answers are work-arounds at this point.  https://status.python.org/incidents/grk0k7sz6zkp  => "Resolved: XMLRPC Search has been permanently disabled. Jan 03, 2022"

Comment: `poetry` so far seems a solid replacement for this missing functionality. Install e.g., either as: `pip3 install --user poetry` (or `pip2`), or e.g., macOS you either use `pip` or can also `sudo port install poetry` (if using macports). See https://pypi.org/project/poetry

Comment: `pip search x-package-name` can be used with the `pip_search` package and an alias bash script described [here](https://github.com/victorgarric/pip_search) to the file where you inserted the script e.g. .bash_alias. Then just run `source ~/.bash_alias` and it will work immediately.

Answer (score 48):

As of December the 14th, 2020, [the `pip search` functionality has been disabled](https://status.python.org/incidents/grk0k7sz6zkp) :

```
$ pip search cast
ERROR: XMLRPC request failed [code: -32500]
RuntimeError: PyPI's XMLRPC API is currently disabled due to unmanageable load and will be deprecated in the near future. See https://status.python.org/ for more information.
```

---

## Alternatives

Here's a little tool called [***pip_search***](https://github.com/victorgarric/pip_search) I've just found that does a simple search but it does the job.

This is `pip_search` v0.0.6 output:

```
$ pip_search pulsemixer
----------------  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name              Description

pulsemixer        pulsemixer - CLI and curses mixer for PulseAudio
pulsectl-asyncio  Asyncio frontend for the pulsectl Python bindings of libpulse
pulsectl          Python high-level interface and ctypes-based bindings for PulseAudio (libpulse)
----------------  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### UPDATE

`pip_search` has been updated, each folder is a clickable (CTRL+click) URL for each project, now it looks like this:

```
$ pip_search pulsemixer
                                            https://pypi.org/search/?q=pulsemixer                                             
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Package             ┃ Version ┃ Released     ┃ Description                                                                     ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│  pulsemixer       │ 1.5.1   │ Apr 11, 2020 │ pulsemixer - CLI and curses mixer for PulseAudio                                │
│  pulsectl-asyncio │ 0.1.7   │ Jun 13, 2021 │ Asyncio frontend for the pulsectl Python bindings of libpulse                   │
│  pulsectl         │ 21.5.18 │ May 22, 2021 │ Python high-level interface and ctypes-based bindings for PulseAudio (libpulse) │
└─────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

To install it, just type:

> `pip install pip_search`

---

There's also another tool that I've just tried called [*pypisearch*](https://github.com/shidenko97/pypisearch).

To install it, just type: `pip install pypisearch`

And it works like this:

```
$ python -m pypisearch pulsemixer
pulsemixer (1.5.1)        [installed 1.5.0] pulsemixer - CLI and curses mixer for PulseAudio
pulsectl-asyncio (0.1.5)  Asyncio frontend for the pulsectl Python bindings of libpulse
pulsectl (21.3.4)         Python high-level interface and ctypes-based bindings for PulseAudio (libpulse)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to me!

Comment: Note that this simply sends a query term to https://pypi.org/search/

Answer (score 15):

After Dec 2020, `search` doesn't work. But `index` does.

`pip index versions <package_name>`

Note:  `pip index` is currently an experimental command. It may be removed/changed in a future release without prior warning.

EDIT: (You can also use `pip index -vv versions <package>` to get verbose output.)

Comment: Seems to be removed.

Comment: `pip index versions requests` works for me with `pip 22.0.4` on Windows. Can you provide more information about what's wrong? Maybe an error message?

Comment: Don't want to necro, but this works fine for me in pip 21.2.3 while `pip search` is deprecated and was blocked by my work vpn. I understand why `pip search` is the accepted answer, but it's not really a solution going forward with newer versions of pip. While experimental, at least this solution is not deprecated.

Comment: This is the best answer for me because there is nothing to install.  It works fine for me on Windows as of 2022.11.04.

Answer (score 13):

1. To search use `pip search QUERY`

   Use `pip help`  and `pip help COMMAND` to learn about all available commands and their options.
2. You can find a complete list of packages here:

   https://pypi.org/

   An index with simpler markup for easier automatic consumption can be found here:

   https://pypi.org/simple/

Comment: what version of pip are you talking about?

Comment: Now the url without the trail slash is the one to go!

Comment: The link sure helped.

Comment: Both the links now refer to the same page

Comment: @arshad thanks for the heads up, I've updated the URLs.

Answer (score 5):

Pip search can solve your problem if you don't want to use it too often. But after regular use I found it hard to read, slow to use and it didn't show infos I sometimes needed (upload time, license, size, etc) so I ended up writing an alternative which I think turned out pretty nice.

It is called yip and it is like pip search on steroids. It supports regex search, colorized output and a menu system which makes installing from search result super easy. If you want to know more or see a screencap [check it out on GitHub](https://www.github.com/balzss/yip).

Comment: yip looks very promising, any similar tool for windows os.?

Answer (score 3):

To see a list of all available packages try running

```
pip search *
```

Comment: then you can pipe to `grep`. kind of like `yum list | grep PATTERN`.

Comment: I just did that, got a list of 102 packages. Asterisk does not appear to work as wildcard. I believe it finds actual asterisk somewhere in the package description. Did a few other tests with asterisk with no apparent system to the results.

Comment: Note that star `*` is a glob in many shells, so it will expand to a list of filenames in the current directory. You could get around that by escaping it with quotes or a backslash.

Comment: I got no results from this using pip 19.1.1.

Comment: It shows exactly 100 packages + 2 log lines (pip 20.0.2). `pip search` has max display packages count.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply install a non-existing version of the package that you want to search. By this way, you can find not only the stable releases, but also the alpha, beta versions like `1.2.3a2`.

```
pip install [package]==666.666.666
```

Comment: Or simply `pip install packagename==`

Answer (score -3):

Use: pip show <package_name>

Comment: This only works if you already have the package installed. The question is asking for functionality to search for available packages i.e. ones not installed. Therefore this is not a solution