# How to get latest version of not installed package using pip?

Tags: python, pip

I want to know, for a package which is not installed in my virtual environment, what is the latest version available.

For example, if I had to install `requests` library, I would want to know the version before installation.

I considered `pip search` but that was deprecated in Python 3.11.

Is there any other way to get the `release version` using some command before installing a Python package ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the currently-experimental `pip index`:

```
C:\>pip index versions requests
WARNING: pip index is currently an experimental command. It may be removed/changed in a future release without prior warning.
requests (2.28.2)
Available versions: 2.28.2, 2.28.1, 2.28.0, 2.27.1, 2.27.0, 2.26.0, 2.25.1, 2.25.0, 2.24.0, 2.23.0, 2.22.0, 2.21.0, 2.20.1, 2.20.0, 2.19.1, 2.19.0, 2.18.4, 2.18.3, 2.18.2, 2.18.1, 2.18.0, 2.17.3, 2.17.2, 2.17.1, 2.17.0, 2.16.5, 2.16.4, 2.16.3, 2.16.2, 2.16.1, 2.16.0, 2.15.1, 2.14.2, 2.14.1, 2.14.0, 2.13.0, 2.12.5, 2.12.4, 2.12.3, 2.12.2, 2.12.1, 2.12.0, 2.11.1, 2.11.0, 2.10.0, 2.9.2, 2.9.1, 2.9.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.0, 2.7.0, 2.6.2, 2.6.1, 2.6.0, 2.5.3, 2.5.2, 2.5.1, 2.5.0, 2.4.3, 2.4.2, 2.4.1, 2.4.0, 2.3.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.0, 1.0.4, 1.0.3, 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.14.2, 0.14.1, 0.14.0, 0.13.9, 0.13.8, 0.13.7, 0.13.6, 0.13.5, 0.13.4, 0.13.3, 0.13.2, 0.13.1, 0.13.0, 0.12.1, 0.12.0, 0.11.2, 0.11.1, 0.10.8, 0.10.7, 0.10.6, 0.10.4, 0.10.3, 0.10.2, 0.10.1, 0.10.0, 0.9.3, 0.9.2, 0.9.1, 0.9.0, 0.8.9, 0.8.8, 0.8.7, 0.8.6, 0.8.5, 0.8.4, 0.8.3, 0.8.2, 0.8.1, 0.8.0, 0.7.6, 0.7.5, 0.7.4, 0.7.3, 0.7.2, 0.7.1, 0.7.0, 0.6.6, 0.6.5, 0.6.4, 0.6.3, 0.6.2, 0.6.1, 0.6.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.4, 0.3.3, 0.3.2, 0.3.1, 0.3.0, 0.2.4, 0.2.3, 0.2.2, 0.2.1, 0.2.0
```

Comment: *Very* experimental; it doesn't appear to be documented at all yet.

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install --dry-run
```

This will show the version and other information about package as if it was being installed, but without actually installing.

Comment: This is good, because it shows all the packages (with version numbers) that would be installed.

Answer (score 3):

You can try 'poetry'.
`poetry search <package>`

Potential duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373473/how-do-i-search-for-an-available-python-package-using-pip).