# How to rank the popularity of open-source components in a package manager?

Tags: components, open-source

Is it based on the number of downloads or the number of dependencies of the open-source components, or from another perspective?

I would like to obtain the rankings of popular components in various package managers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2023, there are multiples package managers per languages, frameworks, OSs available. Each one is providing an analogous but different way of displaying and sorting open-source modules. This functionality is most of the time achievable online with a web browser for certain package managers or with an agregator service.

---

### Agregators services

---

https://libraries.io

---

### Language and frameworks

---

**Python**

pip: better use https://pypi.org/search or see [pip specific thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373473/how-do-i-search-for-an-available-python-package-using-pip)

**Node.js**

npm/yarn: https://www.npmjs.com/search or [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568512/how-to-find-search-find-npm-packages)

**PHP**

Composer: https://packagist.org or [see here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#search)

**Java**

Maven: https://search.maven.org

---

### OS package repositories

---

**Windows**

Chocolatey:  [Choco package search](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages)

**linux**

apt: see your distro specific website.

**MacOS, Linux**

HomeBrew: see [HomeBrewOfficial website](https://brew.sh)